# How to add a reset request after every loop?

Tags: jmeter

I have 1000 threads requesting to a particular url. I use a Synchronizing Timer to make them wait at the end of every loop. How do I let one thread send a request "reset" to my server after each loop?

Edit: I have tried the configuration below, but the threads don't seem to wait, the order is messed up. Essentially I would like the following requests (assuming 5 requests at the same time)

```
request
request
request
request
request
reset
request
request
request
request
request
reset
...
```

[image: Config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arhtur,

First of all 1000 threads is really too much for a machine to handle. You might to have to do distributed load testing. Check this. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Out of 1000 threads, If only one thread has to send a reset request, You can use a If controller - Just allowing only one thread to send the reset request and skipping all other threads. (there could be some other better solution as well. Please share if you find something else).

[image]

There is a chance that when your server is processing all the requests, thread num 1 might get finished before others and send the reset request immediately while your server is processing other requests. It might or might not affect your test. So design your test accordingly. As you know already, each thread is executed independently.

EDIT:

The Sync Timer is not placed correctly in your test.
[image]

When i run the test, I get the results as given below.
For every 5 requests, 1 reset request is sent. (I set the thread count as 5)

[image]

Comment: Good idea! The synchronisation doesn't seem to work though. I've included my config in the question above.

Comment: Has someone done this before? I need this for my thesis, so I would be really grateful!

Comment: For now, I just let all threads fire a reset request, which is ok, but a pity. The normal request and reset request synchronise the requests correctly. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: 'If Controller' approach does not help? What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: It's too late now. The synchronization didn't work. But thanks anyway, you've been a great help!

Comment: Sorry - I was busy with our release. I have updated the answer. Please check if it is helpful.